# Java reading different variables with ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, multithreading, variables, objectinputstream

I have an ObjectInputStream which needs to read two different inputs which are a String and my own created object. I have a thread which constantly waits for an input and depending on the input be it a string or object it will process the result. I need a way for the input to be able to distinguish between the two.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give more details about your problem? A sample code would be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't it a case of doing:

```
if (objectFromStream instanceof YourObejct) {

    YourObject obj = (YourObject) objectFromStream;
    ....

} else if (objectFromStream instanceof String) {

    String str = (String) objectFromStream;

} else {
  // throw excepption..

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the only two choices are Sting and your object then you can try this:

```
    Object obj = ois.readObject();
    if(obj instanceof String){
       String s = (String)obj;
    }else{
       if(obj instanceof MyObject){
          MyObject m = (MyObject)obj;
       }

    }
```